# How many star points is each fertilizer stick worth?

Tags: harvest-moon-two-towns

I know that fertilizer will give 1 star point a day to each crop that it fertilizes, but how many total star points is in one stick of fertilizer? I have a set up of 4 fertilizer spots in my rice paddy and I want to know how many times I need to replace the sticks before the rice will hit 5 stars.